# Haskell - Parse binary stream

Tags: parsing, haskell, binary, bit

I'm new to Haskell, so I'm probably missing something very simple.

I'm having a supprisingly hard time trying to parse a structured binary stream.
The binary stream has varying and conditional parts (like a field which determines how many items follow it (`ncount`), or what type of message follows it (`type`)).

To get a simple working example, I'm trying to parse this hypothetical binary structure:

```
+----------------+---------------+--------------
| Magic (8 bits) | type (3 bits) | type message...
+----------------+---------------+--------------
Type 1:
+----------------+-------------+-------------+-----------------+
|ncount (3 bits) | n1 (3 bits) | n1 (3 bits) | nN (3 bits)...  |
+----------------+-------------+-------------+-----------------+
Type 2:
+----------------+---------------+
|  num1 (7 bits) | num2 (7 bits) |
+----------------+---------------+
...
```

My code so far:

```
{-# LANGUAGE RecordWildCards #-}

module Main where

import Data.Bits
import Data.Binary                      as B
import qualified Data.Binary.Bits.Get   as BG
import qualified Data.ByteString        as BS

data Header = Header {
     magic  :: Word8
    ,mtype  :: Word8
    ,num1   :: Word8
    ,num2   :: Word8
} deriving (Show)

--instance Show (Get Header) where
--    show (Header {..}) = show . magic

parse_header :: B.Get Header
parse_header = BG.runBitGet parse_header'

-- Example, assume type 2 for now
parse_header' :: BG.BitGet Header
parse_header' = do
    magic   <- BG.getWord8 8
    mtype   <- BG.getWord8 3
    num1    <- BG.getWord8 7
    num2    <- BG.getWord8 7
    return $ Header magic mtype num1 num2

main :: IO ()
main = do
    putStrLn "Start"

    -- File containing binary stream
    fstr <- BS.readFile "data/hbin.bin"

    let header = parse_header
        in 
            -- How do I print out Header?
            print header
            -- * No instance for (Show (Get Header)) 
            -- arising from a use of `print'
            -- * In the expression: print header

    putStrLn "\nEnd"
```

In which I get the error:

```
* No instance for (Show (Get Header)) arising from a use of `print'
* In the expression: print header
```

Obviously, I plan to parse this recursively, but for now I can't even see a value I've read.

I've followed https://wiki.haskell.org/Dealing_with_binary_data but this uses Data.Binary.Strict (binary-strict) which doesn't compile on Windows (atleast on mine).

I've also followed https://hackage.haskell.org/package/binary-bits-0.5/docs/Data-Binary-Bits-Get.html but it doesn't show how to use values you have gotten with `getWord8` (Do I need to `put` them into an Int to read them as decimal?)

Again, I'm new to Haskell and not familiar with Monads (which I believe Get is).

Answer (score 2):

`header = parse_header` is only giving a new name to the parser. You need a function to *run* the parser, [there's one here](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/binary-0.8.5.1/docs/Data-Binary-Get.html#v:runGet) (here choosing `runGet` for simplicity, but you should prefer the other one, to handle the error case more easily):

```
runGet :: Get a -> ByteString -> a
```

Note that it takes a *lazy* `ByteString` (`Data.ByteString.Lazy`) instead of a *strict* one (`Data.ByteString`).

```
...
import Data.ByteString.Lazy (toLazy)

...

main = do
  fstr <- BS.readFile "data/hbin.bin"
  let header = runGet parse_header (fromStrict fstr)
  print header
  putStrLn "End"
```